# haskell Couldn't match expected type

Tags: haskell

i have this error can you guys help me please

```
Couldn't match expected type `Pixels' with actual type `[b0]'
    In the return type of a call of `map'
    In the expression: map (map cambio) b
    In an equation for `negative':
        negative (Pixels _ b)
          = map (map cambio) b
          where
              cambio True = False
              cambio False = True
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

this is the code:

```
import qualified Graphics.HGL as G
import qualified Data.Bool 

data Pixel = Pixel { on :: Bool }

data Pixels = Pixels { color :: G.Color, dots :: [[Pixel]] }

negative:: Pixels -> Pixels
negative (Pixels _ b) = map (map cambio) b
    where 
        cambio True = False
        cambio False = True
```

Answer (score 4):

You're telling the compiler that `negative` returns the type `Pixels`, but you're using `map`, which returns a list.  In addition to that, you're trying to map `cambio` over a list of `Pixel`, but `cambio` accepts a `Bool` and returns on as well, and is just the `not` function re-implemented.  You probably want something more like

```
cambio :: Pixel -> Pixel
cambio (Pixel b) = Pixel (not b)

mapPixels :: (Pixel -> Pixel) -> Pixels -> Pixels
mapPixels f (Pixels c ds) = Pixels c (map (map f) ds)

negative :: Pixels -> Pixels
negative pixels = mapPixels cambio pixels
```

The problem is that you have to manually wrap your `[[Pixel]]` result back in the `Pixels` constructor, the compiler does not do this for you.  Since you weren't providing a new `Color` value, how would the compiler know what to fill that parameter to the constructor with?